# Display uploaded image asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to upload image to my folder and the display it in view.
My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
         if (file != null)
                {
                    string pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images"), pic);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                    ViewBag.Path = path;

                }
            return View();
        }
```

My view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Upload";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, 
                            new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{  
    <label for="file">Upload Image:</label> 
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="width: 100%;" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="submit" /> 

}

<h2>Upload</h2>

<img src="@ViewBag.path" alt="Image"/>
```

By doing this, image is not in my view, only alt text. HTML source generated:

```
<img src="C:\Users\D Stag\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Data\Web\images\1232743916lituviai23afp.jpg"/>
```

Image is saved correctly, it exist in that folder.

Comment: You can't use physical file paths for src or href... you need to use an absolute or relative path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of -

> ViewBag.Path = path;

try that this way -

```
ViewBag.Path = String.Format("/images/{0}", pic); //output should be "~/images/image1.jpg"
```

**UPDATE:** There is no need for "~" in the path. Then image displays.

Comment: Doesn't help. Getting soutce code: <img src="~/images/1232743916lituviai23afp.jpg"/>

Comment: Needed to change to @Url.content(@Viewbag.path) and it works, thanks!

Comment: @user3450929, Actually there is no need for "~" in the path. My answer was updated, now it should work fine. Please try. There is no need to use @Url.Content() too, path should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Example** Try like this:

```
<img src="@string.Format("/Image/{0}",pictue._id.ToString())" alt="@pictue.FileName" />
```

Comment: Would you please explain the code a bit, so others understand your solution more easily?